# Change monodevelop default terminal

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, xterm

I search how to change the default terminal (xterm) in monodevelop for console debugging, i want use xfce4-terminal, like all my archlinux do.
I can't find this option in the options of monodevelop.

I try :

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal /usr/bin/xterm
```

This removed the error but don't open xfce4-terminal with `ctrl`+`F5`

I found nothing with my old friend Google

I use Archlinux with i3wm.

Anybody know how to change the default terminal in monodevelop ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Terminal type is defined via the Linux/Gnome PlatformServices AddIn.

The terminals defined are:

- gnome-terminal
- mate-terminal
- kconsole
- xterm (this is the fall back)

If `xfce4-terminal` is interface compatible with one of those first 3, you can "hack" it by setting the environment variable of one of those and symlinking xfce4 to it. The Addin will look in `/bin`, `/usr/bin`,  & `/usr/local/bin` for it, so I would use the `/usr/local/bin` dir....

Or write `xfce4-terminal` support into the `GnomePlatform` Addin ;-) and issue a MonoDevelop pull-request to get the changes into the mainline code base.

Ref:  https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/2945ef1e5db5acca77b48f10c9ce982273480c3b/main/src/addins/GnomePlatform/GnomePlatform.cs#L321

Comment: I tried setting the `KDE_SESSION_VERSION` environment variable, and symlinking `konsole` to `xfce4-terminal`, but it still uses xterm.